# Magento2 Commands not running

Tags: magento-2.2.1

I've installed magento2 on my localserver and when I use PHP bin/Magento c:c for cache cleaning its saying bash: PHP: command not found. Thanks in advance

Comment: You open the xampp and find shell command line run your command

Comment: kindly rephrase your answer .i cant get what you are trying to say!

Comment: You open the first xampp popup and find shell after goes your magento path and run commands

Comment: @MohitPatel thanks for that suggestion but i want to run it from bash

Comment: refer this link :- https://superuser.com/questions/1238410/running-php-works-in-command-prompt-but-not-git-bash

Answer (score 2):

Could you check the $PATH variable for the composer. This might may be the reason for the error

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Run Magento command in xammp shell**

> **Go to your Magento root directory usind cd command.**

Try this link [click here](https://blog.magepsycho.com/configure-bash-shell-magento-2-cli-commands/)

Comment: its is working from shell but doesnt work from git bash

Comment: Check added link